# What internal boards do the Trello Team maintain?

Tags: trello

I recently saw a Trello board about Trello itself, with stuff like usage examples, keyboard shortcuts, etc...

I can't seem to Google-fu it up now. Where is it? Are there other internal Trello boards except the [Trello Dev Board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c)?

I looked around in [Fog Creek's company profile](https://trello.com/fogcreek), and saw a few other boards, but not the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://trello.com/fogcreek

For boards belonging to other Trello app developers see https://trello.com/trelloapps

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you're thinking of the [Trello Resources](https://trello.com/resources) board, although it's not really an "internal" board.

**Public** boards maintained by the Trello team include:

- [Trello Resources Board](https://trello.com/resources)
- [Trello Development Board](https://trello.com/dev)
- [Trello Mobile Board](https://trello.com/mobile)
- [Trello API Board](https://trello.com/api)

We also have several boards that really are internal, which are used for short term projects.